# How to get the dimensions of the widget before build?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to get the dimension of the widget before perform build in flutter.

example I have container with child text.

```
initState(){
 Container _container =
       Container(child: Text('Hello Bala'))
 _container.size// like this
}
```

disclaimer : We can achieve this after build using GlobalKey and WidgetBinding.addPostFrameCallback but I need to get the size without using this.

Comment: *"How to get the dimension of the widget before perform build in flutter."* - you cannot do that

Comment: btw, why would you want to know that `_container.size`?

Comment: I am creating the custom control like grid, for that I need to provide the auto width support

Comment: try `CustomMultiChildLayout` then